# Add UILabel for In App Purchase Product Price

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have in app purchases set up in my app which work fine, however I want to call the 'Product Price' with local currency onto a viewController. I have posted this question before and have got the feedback:

"proUpgradeProduct is a private variable. Make it public by adding is as a method, or a property/sythesize pair. Your problems are not related to in-app purchasing, but rather a lack of basic objective-c knowledge."

I am quite new to this so would appreciate some help. basically, the productPrice variable is in InAppPurchaseSS.m file and I want to call it as a UILabel into a DIFFERENT viewController.

I have these 2 files:

**InAppPurchaseSS.h**

## import

```
#import  "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"

#define kProductPurchasedNotification       @"ProductPurchased"
#define kProductPurchaseFailedNotification  @"ProductPurchaseFailed"
#define kProductPurchaseCancelledNotification  @"ProductPurchaseCancelled"

@interface InAppPurchaseSS : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    SKProductsRequest*   productsRequest;
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    UIAlertView* waitingAlert;
    BOOL isTransactionOngoing;
    IBOutlet UILabel *productPriceLabel;
}

@property (retain) SKProductsRequest*   productsRequest;
@property (retain) NSArray * products;
@property (retain) SKProductsRequest *request;
@property (assign) BOOL isTransactionOngoing;

+ (InAppPurchaseSS *) sharedHelper;

-(id)init;
- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases;
-(void)restoreInAppPurchase;

@end
```

**InAppPurchaseSS.m**

```
//

#import "InAppPurchaseSS.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation InAppPurchaseSS

@synthesize products;
@synthesize request;
@synthesize productsRequest;
@synthesize isTransactionOngoing;

static InAppPurchaseSS * _sharedHelper;

+ (InAppPurchaseSS *) sharedHelper {

    if (_sharedHelper != nil) {
        return _sharedHelper;
    }
    _sharedHelper = [[InAppPurchaseSS alloc] init];
    return _sharedHelper;

}

-(id)init {

    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        isTransactionOngoing=NO;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }

    return self;

}


- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Received products results...");
    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;    
    NSLog(@"Number of product:%i : %@",[response.products count],response.products);
    NSArray *product = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [product count] == 1 ? [[product firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    [productPriceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"Product Price: %@",proUpgradeProduct.price]];




}



-(void)restoreInAppPurchase
{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet"  message:@"Sorry, no internet connection found"   delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    }
    waitingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restoring..."  message:@"Please Wait...\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitingAlert show];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}




- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    if ([productIdentifier isEqual: @""]) {
        NSLog(@"No IAP Product ID specified");
        return;
    }

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet" message:@"Sorry, no internet connection found"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    } 
     isTransactionOngoing=YES;

    waitingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchasing..." message:@"Please Wait...\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitingAlert show];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0) {
        SKMutablePayment *payment = [[SKMutablePayment alloc] init];
        payment.productIdentifier = productIdentifier;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}



-(void)enableFeature
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Restore completed transaction failed");

}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

//
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
    isTransactionOngoing=NO;
    [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    if (wasSuccessful)
    {
        [self enableFeature];

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!!" message:@"You have succesfully Purchases." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"successbuy" object:self];
    }
    else
    {
      [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:transaction.error.localizedDescription  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
    }
}


- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"succesfull transaction");
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"transaction is restored");
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}


// called when a transaction has failed
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    isTransactionOngoing=NO;

    NSLog(@"failed transaction called");

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction failed called");
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);

        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"user cancel transaction");
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods

// called when the transaction status is updated
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"transaction status updated");
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
} 

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

I have another viewController set up where I want to call the Local Product Price with UILabel. Let's assume this is called SecondViewController. I know that in InAppPurchaseSS.m I have a field for proUpgradeProduct.price but I need to call this as a UI label with the local currency

It may be something obvious Im overlooking but I'd appreciate some help with this

Thank you

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing the C++ tag should be removed from this question.

Answer (score 0):

In the method where you load the products each product should have a variable which contains the price as well as the label. Unfortunately, I don't know which one but I think it's the SKProduct. See if it contains any variables.

**EDIT:**

It's the `proProduct.localizedLabel` and `proProduct.localizedPrice` that you are looking for!

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I looked again and saw that you were more precise about your question. I would recommend you to save these as NSString.

For instance:

in your .h file you create a property.

```
@interface SomethingController : UIViewController {


//random stuff




}
@property NSString price;
@property NSString title;


@end
```

Now set the

```
self.price = proProduct.localizedPrice
```

and

```
self.title = proProduct.localizedLabel
```

somewhere in the .m file.

Now in your other viewcontroller where you want to show these you create an instance somewhere in the viewcontroller.m file.
First you import the SomethingController.h which contains the variables you are looking for.
At the top of your viewcontroller.m file of the viewcontroller you want to display the data in you write: `#import SomethingController.h`
Then you create an instance of it to get the data.

```
SomethingController * something = [SomethingController alloc];
```

Now you can access the data in your other viewcontroller by writing:

```
something.price
```

to access the price and

```
something.title
```

to access the label.

Comment: I use SomethingController as a code name for your InAppPurchaseSS file